Order logic and implications
In order logic, prove or disprove that if $$\models \alpha \implies \models \beta,$$ then for every structure U, $$U \models \alpha \implies U \models \beta.$$
I know that the above statement is false. I keep struggling with the fact that $\models \alpha \implies \models \beta,$ which, to me, means that $v(\alpha)=v(\beta)=1$ for all possible valuations; so, choosing a specific $U$ for $U \models \alpha \implies U \models \beta$ gives $[\alpha]_{U}=[\beta]_U.$ What is my mistake? What is the counterexample?

To form a counter-example, we need to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so that
$$ (\models \alpha) \implies (\models \beta) $$
$$ \lnot (\models \alpha) \lor (\models \beta) $$
are true and
$$ \forall U ((U \models \alpha) \implies (U \models \beta)) $$
is false, meaning
$$ \exists U ((U \models \alpha) \mathbin{\;\not\!\!\!\implies} (U \models \beta)) $$
$$ \exists U ((U \models \alpha) \land \lnot (U \models \beta)) $$
is true. So $U \models \alpha$ is true, $U \models \beta$ is false. Of course if $\models \beta$ is true, then $U \models \beta$ is also true. So $\models \beta$ must be false. Since $\models \beta$ is false, from the assumption we must have $\lnot \models \alpha$ is true, $\models \alpha$ is false.
A simple example with $\models \alpha$ false but $U \models \alpha$ true is $\alpha = p$ and $[p]_U = 1$. To get $\models \beta$ false and $U \models \beta$ false, we can just take the contradiction $\beta = \bot$. (Or if you'd rather, $\beta = q$ and $[q]_U = 0$.)
So with structure $U$ evaluating $p$ as true, $(\models p) \implies (\models \bot)$ is vacuously true ($p$ is not a tautology) but $(U \models p) \implies (U \models \bot)$ is false.

The trick is that the first one may hold vacupusly; i.e. if $\alpha$ is not a tautology, the $\vDash \alpha$ is False and thus "$\text { if } \vDash \alpha, \text { then } \vDash \beta$" holds.
Consider this simple example: $\text { if } \vDash p, \text { then } \vDash p \land q$.
You have to note that $\vDash \alpha$ is $U \vDash \alpha, \text {for every } U$.
What is instead: $\text {if } U \vDash \alpha, \text { then } U \vDash \beta, \text { for every } U$?
It means that in every interpretation where $\alpha$ is true, also $\beta$ is.
What happens with $p \vDash p \land q$?
Obviously it not holds, because a valutaion such that p is true and q is false is enough to show that $p$ does not imply $p \land q$.

But $p\models p \wedge q$ is in that case a assumption? So we force $[p]=[q]=1$? What we do after that?

But in that case what we are proving?

But what is the relation between $U\models \alpha$ and $U\models \beta$ with this? For me, would be more effective with expressions of order logic, with quantifiers for example
